# Using google account as xmpp bot

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I'm developing a chat application similar to any Live Chat software. I'm planning to set up this application using google accounts that will act as bots managing all the messages from the web to my users.

Do you know if google have some limitations to set up this kind of accounts that will probably   handle thousands of messages and a roster of, lets say hundreds of contacts?

This bots will be configured from Google Apps for Business, not a free gmail account.

Thanks for your orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed an XMPP bot based on a Google account running as the "server user".

I havent had any problems with the account and it has worked flawless for about a year.
129 users on the "server user" and approx 10K messages has been routed this month.

Comment: Thanks kincaid. I've decided to have my own XMPP server because I suspect google will block me